# Angular6 How to bind share data with sibling with service so that each instance has its reference seperatly

Tags: angular, service, rxjs

[As i click on a field on middle from, it ahould poplate its schema with right component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff8VE.png)

it is working good in case of object with different data, but when i append same object in array in that case it changes both objects in case i change one object on rigt panel.

Using Service to share data between these sibing components based on click event on middel component.
Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before pushing it into the array just deep clone it using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) command. This will strip the memory mapping to different locations and hence they won't be linked

Comment: Oh Wow, it worked. spend entire day scratching my head about my service code and rxjs subject as i thought they are something i am missing about.

Comment: Can you explain me why my simple pusing was not working in simple terms as i was using rxjs subject observable to share and subcribe to data change....

Comment: Its basically how javascript works.
If I create a object say objA it will be given a memory location say 0x000A (imaginary).
If I write objB = objA then both objects will be referring to same memory location.
In case of pushing this to array you are creating multiple copies of same object like arrayA[1]=objA arrayB[2]=objA where all will be mapped to same location.

Hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: Yes got your explainiation very well. Thank you very much for your quick answer. Looks like today Angular is testing my core skills :)  Firstly spend hours on this "Angular2 change detection: ngOnChanges not firing for nested objects in array" and then this. Long live SO... ;)

Comment: That's the fun part. :)

Comment: Can you please help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549388/angular-how-to-test-multiple-child-component-rendering-using-ngswitch-and-ngfor